# System application in Android

Tags: java, android, android-framework, android-applicationinfo

How exactly Android determines if an application is a `system application` with root privilege?

I know that for such applications, `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM` will be enabled, and those applications must declare shared user id as `"android.uid.system"` in their `Manifest` file.
Along with that there is another criteria, where an application located in `/system/app` should also be treated as System application.

I searched the source code for PackageMangerService.java in AOSP where I observed that if shared user id is `android.uid.system` then the application is assigned the flag as `FLAG_SYSTEM`.

But I guess, the applications which are available in `/system/app` do not contain the shared user id as `android.uid.system` then how do they get this flag `FLAG_SYSTEM` enabled for them?

Comment: System applications do not have "root privilege". Having root access and being installed on the `/system` partition are not related.

Comment: @CommonsWare In that case, I am actually confused between the two and want to get complete information about the both. What are the feature/traits of each and how to convert a certain app into system app and/or provide it root access? Could you please clarify my doubt, or at least redirect me ?

Comment: @darthvading No apps will have root privileges. If a device has been rooted an application can invoke su, if installed, to perform actions as root but those applications are running as standard users.

*system* is a special user defined in android to have additional privleges. http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h#36 describes the mapping for special users.

If it is a factory device, without root, you will not be able to install an application as the system user.

Answer (score 1):

> if an application is a 'system application' with root privilege

It must be signed with right, system certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The apps in `Android` devices can be **System apps** or **User apps**, this is only **based on their installation location**.

- User apps are placed in the `/data` partition of your Android phone, which is the part of the internal memory made available for user data and apps.
- System apps are those installed in `/system` partition.

> Wow... that's all? Great! Sound easy... how can I do it?

May sound easy, but it is not, you will need to:

- Root you phone
- Add valid signed secure cert
- Give permissions
- And more headaches...

But is not impossible either, [check this tutorial](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/).

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha, I had read the code in PackageManagerService.java before. It has a observer to check if any files in `/system/priv-app/` directory has changed. And it will install the app if there is a new apk file. Then the system will set the `pkgFlags` with `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_PRIVILEGED`

the following is the code in PackageManagerService in Android 5.0:

```
private PackageParser.Package scanPackageLI(File scanFile, int parseFlags, int scanFlags,
        long currentTime, UserHandle user) {
    ....
    if (locationIsPrivileged(scanFile)) {
        updatedPkg.pkgFlags |= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_PRIVILEGED;
    }
    ....
}
```